# Grandparent Folder Name To File Name

Tags: powershell

I have a script that runs when I specify the exact directory of c:\script\19\ the problem is, have other folders in the c:\script such as 18, 17, 16. The script I have is appending the 19 in front of all of the files. How do I get this to look at the grandparent of the file it's renaming and append it? An example of how it's working is files like this:

```
c:\script\18\00000001\Plans.txt
c:\script\19\00001234\Plans.txt
c:\script\17\00005678\App.txt
```

But my script is renaming the files like this

```
c:\script\18\00000001\19-0001 Plans.txt
c:\script\19\00001234\19-1234 Plans.txt
c:\script\17\00005678\19-5678 App.txt
```

My script is this:

```
 $filepath = Get-ChildItem "C:script\" -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object {
$parent = $_.Parent  
$grandparent =  $_.fullname | Split-Path -Parent | Split-Path -Parent | Split-Path -Leaf
    }
Get-ChildItem "C:\Script\" –recurse –file | 
Where-Object {$_.Name –notmatch ‘[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]’} | 
rename-item -NewName {$grandparent + '-' + $_.Directory.Name.SubString($_.Directory.Name.length -4, 4) + ' ' + $_.Name}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to combine string-splitting with the [`-split` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) with a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) (which you've tried to use):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Script –Recurse –File -Exclude [0-9][0-9]-[0-9]* |
  Rename-Item -NewName { 
    # Split the full path into its components.
    $names = $_.FullName -split '\\'
    # Compose the new file name from the relevant components and output it.
    '{0}-{1} {2}' -f $names[-3], $names[-2].Substring($names[-2].Length-4), $_.Name 
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the renaming operation; remove it to perform actual renaming.

Note how `-Exclude` is used with a wildcard expression directly with `Get-ChildItem` to exclude files that already have the target name format.</sup>

The main reason your original didn't work is that you calculated *single, static* 
`$parent` and `$grandparent` values, instead of deriving the input path-specific values from each input path.

Additionally, your `$grandparent` calculation was needlessly complicated; [Gert Jan Kraaijeveld's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54257636/45375) shows a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

To get the grandparent of a $file object:

```
$file.Directory.Parent
```

The parent directory of a file is the 'Directory' member of the file object.

The parent directory of a directory is the 'Parent' member of the directory object.

It is not hard, but confusing it sure is...

---

**Edit**

You asked for my solution:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\script -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
  $parent = $_.Directory.Name
  $grandparent = $_.Directory.Parent.Name
  Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "$grandparent-$($parent.Substring($parent.length-4,4)) $($_.name)" 
}
```

I used the -file parameter of Get-ChildItem to get only files from the folder structure. I'm not sure that suits in your situation

Comment: Thanks for this, but in the code, at what part do I place this? I tried for the $grandparent = and in the rename-item sections, but it just ignores it and begins the file name with the dash.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I added in my other part where the objects didn't match and it works.

Comment: You said you see more potential problems, but Edited your answer using most of code with your change. Are there other potential issues? Any help with those is much appreciated.

Comment: +1, but for efficiency I suggest piping to `Rename-Item` directly via a delay-bind script block: `Get-ChildItem .... | Rename-Item -NewName { ... }` - that way, `Rename-Item` doesn't have to be reinvoked for every input file.

Comment: @Will on closer inspection it was not too bad :-) Removed the comment

Answer (score 0):

In each folder you can run the script to add grandparents name to the filenames in that folder:

```
get-ChildItem *.* | ForEach-Object {
   $grandParent = $_.Directory.Parent.Name
   $new_name = $grandParent+ "_"+ $_.Name
   Rename-Item $_.Name -NewName $new_name
}
```